# How to loop through a list of variables to pass into stored procedure parameters in T-SQL

Tags: loops, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes in two parameters: a beginning and an end date in the format YYYYMM. The format of this field (in the underlying table is simply int).

The stored procedure essentially takes movements or differences between two periods and it is required that this movement is monthly for example the amount movement between 202301 and 202302.

What I want to do is to be able to pass each incremental date to the stored procedure (perhaps from a table with two columns: key, year_month) for example pass in 202301 and 202302 and insert the data into a pre-created table, then 202302 and 202303 and pass the data again into the pre-created table etc.

How could I loop through such a table (something like for each row...) and continually pass the variables to the parameters of the stored procedure?

Or maybe I don't need to create and loop through a table; perhaps using something like the date add function?

Thanks

Comment: Looping is generally a very slow method of doing things in SQL Server; are you *sure* a loop is what you need here? Perhaps you would be better off taking a step back and explaining the underlying problem.

Comment: Hi @ThomA The underlying problem is that I would like to run the SP over say a 6 month period but because it is movement based and the monthly movement is needed I cannot input into the parameter dates 202301, 202306 for example because that would give me a movement over 6 months. So I have to manually run it 6 times changing the dates for each month from 202301 to 202396

Comment: Or maybe this is something I need SSIS for with it's loop containers?

Comment: Show us some data and your expected result! After that we can help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/cursors-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

In general it's not a good idea to use cursors in SQL because SQL is a set-based language (And RBAR operations should be avoided).  But if you already have the stored procedures in place and cannot change them for whatever reason, you could try something like :

```
DECLARE @fromDate INT;
DECLARE @toDate INT;
DECLARE @theDate DATE;
 
DECLARE cursor_example CURSOR FOR
SELECT TheDate
FROM dbo.allDates
 
OPEN cursor_example
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_example into @theDate
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    SET @fromDate = DATEPART(year,@theDate) * 100 + DATEPART(month,@theDate)
    SET @toDate = DATEPART(year,@theDate) * 100 + DATEPART(month,@theDate)
    EXEC dbo.MyStoredProcedure @fromDate, @toDate; 
 
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_example into @theDate
END

CLOSE cursor_example;
DEALLOCATE cursor_example;
```

Comment: Thanks Wouter. I will trey this solution later when I have time. From the face of it it looks like it might be something that I need. Yes you're right I can't really change or modify the stored procedure.